# Rhombus collision detection for game

Tags: java, oop, collision-detection

I'm working on a simple game,in Java, and I need to make the rhombus-rectangle collision detection. I did it, but I don't know how to stop the player when he touch the rhombus. My solutoin is wrong, because when the player touch the rhombus, he can't anymore move. I want that the player can move around, when he touch the obstacle he stop, but after he can still move.

Some one can help me?

This is my Java code:

The player class:

```
public class Player{
    // I move the player with KeyListener
    public int[] xp,yp;
    public boolean collide;
    public boolean stop;

    public Player(int[]xp,int[]yp){
        stop = false;
        this.xp = xp; 
        this.yp = yp;
        collide = false;
    }
    public void show(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        if(collide){
            g2d.fillPolygon(new Polygon(this.xp,this.yp,4));
        }
        g2d.drawPolygon(new Polygon(this.xp,this.yp,4));
    }
    public void move(int dx, int dy){
        if(!stop){
            for(int i = 0; i < xp.length; i++){
                xp[i] += dx;
                yp[i] += dy;
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean testIntersec(Polygon poly1){
        Area A1 = new Area(new Polygon(this.xp,this.yp,4));
        A1.intersect(new Area(poly1));
        return !A1.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The Panel class:

```
public void init(){
    int[] x = {0,50,50,0};
    int[] y = {0,0,50,50};

    int[] x1 = {0,50,25,-25};
    int[] y1 = {0,0,25,25};

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x[i] += 300;
        y[i] += 300;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x1[i] += 600;
        y1[i] += 600;
    }
    player = new Player(x,y);
    other = new Player(x1,y1);
}

// main loop
public void update(){
    player.update();

    if(player.testIntersec(new Polygon(other.xp,other.yp,4))){
        player.collide = true;
        player.stop = true;
    }else{
        player.collide = false;
        player.stop = false;
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    player.show(g2d);
    other.show(g2d);
}
```

Comment: What most likely happens is your player character gets stuck inside the rhombus, so each call to `testIntersec` returns true from that point onwards, and you don't allow the player to step outside the area. You should choose a different method of stopping player from moving, or maybe push him outside the rhombus area before stopping his movements.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Great Idea! But how can I know with which side I'm colliding?

Comment: You'd need to change how you're currently handling collision - it's not flexible enough.